# (∃!x)A(x) is equivalent to (∃x)A(x) ∧ (∀y)(∀z) (A(y) ∧ A(z) ⇒ y = z)

Tags: quantifiers

I have to prove this using real world examples and I don't know how. 
I tried to do this with nicotine, but the unique existential quantifier confuses me.

Comment: Why are these equivalent? What if $A(x)$ was the statement $x=1$?

Comment: $A(x)$ could be $x$ is queen of England or $x$ is a natural satellite of Earth $x$ is my wife (if bigamy is unlawful)...

Comment: @benji if $A(x)\cong x=1$ then the statement just assert that there a unique 1, both parts says so. If $\exists xA(x)$ then there is a 1, it may not be unique but at least we can confirm existence, but if $y=1$ and $z=1$ then, obviously, $z=y$. So it is unique.

Comment: @sufronausea Thanks for the clarification. After reading the answer, I realize I completely misunderstood what the symbol meant. I thought it meant "there doesn't exist x such that..." but seeing that it means there is exactly one, then this makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Hard to to tell you how to prove it without knowing what def'n of "$\exists!$" you are given, as the RHS would, to me, be a def'n of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so let's say that $A(x)$ means $x$ is a perfect milkshake.

then $\exists ! x A(x)$ states that there is exactly one perfect milkshake.

The $\exists x A(x) \land \forall y \forall z ((A(y) \land A(z)) \rightarrow y=z)$ statement states two things:

$\exists x A(x)$ ... This means that there is at least one perfect milkshake

$\forall y \forall z ((A(y) \land A(z)) \rightarrow y=z)$ ... This means that if you ever have two perfect milkshakes, then they are really just one and the same ...  meaning that you can never have two *different* perfect milkshakes, and thus you can have only at most one perfect milkshake.

But if you have at least one perfect milkshake, *and* you can't have more than one, then you must have exactly one!

So, the two statements say the same thing!